# If $f+g$ is measurable, are $f$ and $g$ measurable?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

If $f$ and $g$ are measurable, then so is $f+g$.
But if $f+g$ is measurable, are $f$ and $g$ measurable?
I think they are but I can't prove it.
I know that
$$
\{f(x)+g(x)<\alpha \}
=\bigcap_{r\in \mathbb Q}\{f(x)<r\}\cap \{g(x)<\alpha -r\},
$$
but it doesn't really help.

So maybe it's wrong. And if the case it's wrong, if $f+g$ and $f$ are measurable, is $g$ measurable ?

Comment: I guess you mean $\bigcup_{r\in \mathbb Q}$ instead of $\bigcap_{r\in \mathbb Q}$.

Answer (score 6):

**Hint**

**Question 1 :** Let $\mathcal N$ be a non-measurable set. What do you think about $$\boldsymbol 1_{\mathcal N}+\boldsymbol 1_{\mathcal N^c} \ \ ?$$

**Question 2 :** $$f=(f+g)+(-g).$$

Comment: Good answer. Can I ask the same question with $gf$ instead of $g+f$ ? I mean, if $fg$ is measurable, what about $f$ and $g$ ? And if not, if $fg$ is measurable and $g$ is measurable, what about $f$ ?

Comment: What if $g = 0$?

Comment: @John: 1) what about $\boldsymbol 1_{\mathcal N}\cdot \boldsymbol 1_{\mathcal N^c}$ ? 2) Given by MinusOne-Twefth, what about $f=\boldsymbol 1_{\mathcal N}$ and $g=0$ ?

Answer (score 3):

Take any non measurable function $f$ and take $g=-f$. The answer to the second question is yes, $g$ is measurable because $f=(f+g)-f$.